# Standalone alternatives to --webtex for pandoc

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, pandoc, epub

I am trying to create an epub2 from markdown (from a jupyter notebook) that includes embedded latex formulas using pandoc. The only option I can see is to render the latex as graphics using --webtex but whenever I try I get some timeouts

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?...'
```

Now I am wondering how to replace webtex with a local processor (e.g. latexit). Or is there another way?

Comment: maybe something with your network? works for me https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?x=2 as does this: `echo '$x^2$' | pandoc --webtex --self-contained -o foo.html`

Comment: Yes, short formulas usually work for me as well but when trying to translate a longer text I get several timeouts. It also seems to be silly to use a web service to do latex when your computer has its own latex installation.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative option is to use GladTeX ( https://github.com/humenda/GladTeX ) as a pandoc filter.

the pipeline would be something like:

```
pandoc -s input_file.md -t json | gladtex -P -  | pandoc -s -f json -o output-file.epub
```

you can also do it step by step or make further configurations with gladtex (see `man gladtex`)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that latex-formulae-pandoc does the job:
https://github.com/liamoc/latex-formulae
Thanks to Liam O'Connor for implementing it and offering useful advice! However, the package doesn't work with the current version of pandoc but I had to downgrade to pandoc-2.7.3 but then it works perfectly.

Liam comments:

> Pandoc-types version 1.20 switches things over to Text and other
>   changes that are probably compatibility-breaking

If I find some time I'll have a look at this.

Comment: Can you show me how to use it plugin?